# Prestashop 1.7 - error 500 when accessing General Preference or Administration

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Everything works fine if I enable debug mode. There is no error shown. When I disable debug mode I get error 500 when I want to access Preferences or Administration. I deleted /var/cache folder, cleared browser and nothing helps. This is happening after I update P1.7.4.2 to P1.7.5.0. The thing is that on localhost works fine only on my server. Both are on PHP5.6 
What is wrong with it?

When trying to access eg. Preferences there is only this error showing in /var/logs/prod.log

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable
>   Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Search\SearchParameters::__construct() must
>   be an instance of
>   PrestaShopBundle\Entity\Repository\AdminFilterRepository, instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given, called in
>   /PRESTA175/var/cache/prod/ContainerUdabyc4/getPrestashop_Core_Admin_SearchParametersService.php
>   on line 8 and defined" at
>   /PRESTA175/src/Core/Search/SearchParameters.php line 50
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException(code: 0):
>   Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Search\SearchParameters::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   PrestaShopBundle\Entity\Repository\AdminFilterRepository, instance
>   of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given, called in
>   /PRESTA175/var/cache/prod/ContainerUdabyc4/getPrestashop_Core_Admin_SearchParametersService.php
>   on line 8 and defined at
>   /PRESTA175/src/Core/Search/SearchParameters.php:50)"} []

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

If you remove the cache folder and clear browser cache and you still have some problem with error 500 in some cases then you need **restart the apache on the server**. I found out that I have to restart apache every time I do update from 1.7.4.x to 1.7.5.0 (I did several tests). I didn't have this problem on my localhost and I didn't have this problem when only updating from like 1.7.4.2 to 1.7.4.4 (under 1.7.5.0). I don't get it that, because the apache version on the server is the same as on my lh.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution

Upgrading from 1.7.4.4 to 1.7.5.1 using Cloudways hosting and what suggested felixRo was not enough in my case.
First of all I cleared all files in the var/cache/ folder and then:

- I restarted Apache
- I restarted Memcached
- I restarted Nginix
- I restarted MySQL

Finally I restarted the whole server as well. This did the trick.
Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with deleting the PS_ROOT/var/cache/prod/class_index.php and PS_ROO/var/cache/dev/class_index.php.

Comment: As I said I deleted cache folder.

Comment: You don't have to delete the cache folder :-( just the cache/prod/smarty/compile/*, the cache/dev/smarty/compile/* and the class_index.php so it'll regenerate.

Comment: I wanted be sure that there is no cache at all.

Comment: I have seen this error 500 happen with debug on a few times and it was always a matter of removing the class_index.php file along with the clearing of the compile directory, that is why I suggested you try with the cache directory as it is by default and only those two things altered (the compile dir cleared and the class file removed).